# Finding eigenvector reduces to identity matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm computing some eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

What does it mean, when taking a found eigenvalue $\lambda$ and trying to find its corresponding eigenvector $x$ (from the equality $\lambda x-Ax=0$) reduces to identity matrix?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223137/eigenvector-of-matrix-that-reduces-to-identity) it's claimed that it means that eigenvalue $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue. But how is that reasonable? Or is it possible that eigenvalues can be rejected, even after they were found as solutions to the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: If $\lambda$ really is an eigenvalue of $A$, for example if $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then it won’t happen that $\lambda I - A$ reduces to the identity matrix.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Ok so then when this happens there's always a calculation error somewhere.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @mavavilj: Yes, if this happens then you made an error somewhere.

Comment: It means you've made a mistake some place in the computation.  The roots of the characteristic polynomial $\lambda$ will always produce a singular matrix $\lambda I - A$.  Thus $(\lambda I - A)x = 0 $ will always have a nontrivial solution.